# Is it possible to change the color of the selection outline indicator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Is it possible to change the way the outline visually appears when you make a selection in CS6 Photoshop, without affecting how it works? For instance, it is sometimes hard to see the selection outline when working near patterned black and white areas of an image. For instance, could I make it orange? Or perhaps make it thicker?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **no**. The appearance of the selection "marching ants" can not be changed.

Comment: "**Marching ants**", I love it!!